# Optional arguments in Lithium?

Tags: php, routes, lithium

I wish to make `:offset` optional.

```
Router::connect('/some_page/{:offset}/', ...
```

So:

```
Router::connect('/some_page/', ...
Router::connect('/some_page/{:offset}/', ...
```

Both go to the same route. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

First change the order:

```
Router::connect('/some_page/{:offset}/', ...
Router::connect('/some_page/', ...
```

Then in the controller just check if the `offset` is set:

```
isset($this->request->params['offset'])
```